# Pure CSS - Using mask-image and radial-gradient to make diamond like form

Tags: css, radial-gradients

I am trying to make some diamond form in pure CSS, trying to use mask-image and radial-gradient but I don't quite succeed.

The 2 form I like to do are :

[image: Diamond empty]

[image: Diamond filled]

I tried something to alter a block of color black like

```
width: 20px;
height: 20px;
background: #000;
-webkit-mask-image: radial-gradient(circle 7px at top, transparent 7px, black 50%);
```

I don't know how to solve my problem and even it is doable through only pure CSS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't really need mask here. Multiple `radial-gradient()` can do it

```css
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px;
  --c:transparent 90%,#000 92% 98%,transparent; /* adjust this */
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top   left  ,var(--c)) top left,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top   right ,var(--c)) top right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--c)) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--c)) bottom right;
  background-size:51% 51%; /* add this (each layer take half the height and width) */
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
} 

.alt {
  --c:transparent 90%,#000 92%; /* we simply remove the last transparent for the full shape */
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box alt"></div>
```

Mask can be useful in case you want a fancy background:

```css
.box {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:10px;
  background:linear-gradient(45deg,red,blue);
  --c:transparent 90%,#000 92% 98%,transparent; /* adjust this */
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top   left  ,var(--c)) top left,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at top   right ,var(--c)) top right,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom left ,var(--c)) bottom left,
    radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom right,var(--c)) bottom right;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 51%; /* add this (each layer take half the height and width) */
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
} 

.alt {
  --c:transparent 90%,#000 92%; /* we simply remove the last transparent for the full shape */
}

body {
  background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>

<div class="box alt"></div>
```